# Where are configured the folders icons in Thunderbird?

Tags: thunderbird

Something happened to my thunderbird profile: now every folder in the folder three pane on the left has the same standard yellow folder icon.

I mean that the special icons for INBOX, Trash etc. are missing.

I've tried to temporarily rename the profile folder, then restarting Thunderbird, now all the special icons are back again.

So the problem appear to be in the profile folder.

I don't want to delete my profile folder cause it contain all my emails.... :-(

any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just ran into the same problem after Thunderbird update to version 22 beta.

In my case, an extension called "Remove Duplicate Messages (Alternate)" was guilty.

Try disabling all the extensions, and then turn them on one by one to find the culprit.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple way to get directly to the folder :

In Thunderbird,

- Click on the "Help" (?) menu, then "Repair information" ;
- In the new tab, click on the "Open the matching folder" button right to "Profile folder" ;
- Now open the "Mail" folder.

Then please don't forget to close Thunderbird before touching anyhting there.

NOTE :

In case your question was related to repairing corrupted folders, please check this how-to, listing all the possible cases and cures, depending on your email setup :

[How to rebuild missing trash bin (and possible other system) folder(s) in Mozilla Thunderbird](https://superuser.com/questions/1121423/solved-how-to-rebuild-missing-trash-bin-and-possible-other-system-folders/1121424#1121424)